# Not getting desired output from iconv

Tags: php

```
function getCleanUrl($str, $replace=array(), $delimiter='-'){
    setlocale(LC_COLLATE, 'en_GB');
        if(!empty($replace)) {
        $str = str_replace((array)$replace, ' ', $str);
        }

    $clean = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $str);
    $clean = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/_|+ -]/", '', $clean);
    $clean = strtolower(trim($clean));
    $clean = preg_replace("/[\/_|+ -]+/", $delimiter, $clean);

    return $clean;

     }
```

When I make call to the above function:

```
   $str = "cTänk efter nu – förr'n vi föser dig bort";
   $replace = array("'","!",".");
   $cleanString = getCleanUrl($str,$replace);
```

OUTPUT: $cleanString ==>> `ctnk-efter-nu-frr-n-vi-fser-dig-bort`

It should be `ctank-efter-nu-forr-n-vi-foser-dig-bort`

For reference: http://cubiq.org/the-perfect-php-clean-url-generator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `setlocale()` line. The locale specified probably doesn't exist. Try this:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_GB.UTF-8');
```

If not, try:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8');
```

To list locales installed on your system, execute the following by the command line:

```
$ locale -a
```